# LINQ Select newest records that have distinct ForeignKeyId column

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT 
   table1.Id AS EinAusgangId, 
   table1.Ausgabedatum, 
   table1.Rueckgabedatum, 
   table1.WerkzeugId, 
   cpmWerkzeug.Name
FROM cpmEinAusgang AS table1 
INNER JOIN cpmWerkzeug ON table1.WerkzeugId = cpmWerkzeug.Id
WHERE table1.Id = (SELECT MAX(Id) AS Expr1 
                   FROM dbo.cpmEinAusgang
                   WHERE table1.WerkzeugId = WerkzeugId)
```

My aim is to convert the whole query into a LINQ statement for further use in a .Net Application. I already converted joined tables to LINQ but is it also possible to use a `select` in the `where` clause?

This is what I got so far, which gives me almost the same result as the SQL statement above, but has major errors when the table `cpmEinAusgang` contains more then one record for one `cpmWerkzeug`

```
using (var dbContext = new cpmEntities())
{
  var werkzeuge = from w in dbContext.cpmWerkzeug
  join e in dbContext.cpmEinAusgang
  on w.Id equals e.WerkzeugId
  where e.Rueckgabedatum == null
  orderby w.Name
  select w;

  return werkzeuge.ToList();
}
```

Has anyone an idea how to achieve the above sql in linq?
Thanks for your help. :)

EDIT:solved (see below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var werkzeugeImUmlauf = from w in dbContext.cpmWerkzeug
                                join e in dbContext.cpmEinAusgang
                                on w.Id equals e.WerkzeugId
                                where e.Id == dbContext.cpmEinAusgang.Where(x => x.WerkzeugId == e.WerkzeugId).Max(x => x.Id) select w;
```

This is the final solution. As mentioned by Mittal in his answer, it is possible to write a sub-query in LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can write `Sub Query` in LINQ as well.

```
 var werkzeuge = from w in dbContext.cpmWerkzeug
  join e in dbContext.cpmEinAusgang
  on w.Id equals e.WerkzeugId
  where w.id = (dbContext.cpmEinAusgang.Max(x => x.id)) AND w.WerkzeugId = WerkzeugId
```

Comment: almost. thanks for helping me with the "subquery". that gave me the final hint. btw: "AND" is not existing in LINQ it would be &&. And after changing somme hirarchy and variables I found the solution (see marked solution)
1+ for helping me